# I load a seccomp filter to disallow fork(), but can still use fork() with no problem

Tags: c, linux, seccomp

I'm trying to create a seccomp filter that would blacklist the use of fork(). This is my code:

```
#include <seccomp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) {
        int rc = -1;
        int pid_t;
        scmp_filter_ctx ctx;
        ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_ALLOW);

        // possible issue for torsocks: needs arg count
        rc = seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, SCMP_SYS(fork), 0);
        printf("seccomp rule add return value: %d\n", rc);
        rc = seccomp_load(ctx);
        printf("seccomd_load return value: %d\n", rc);
        pid_t = fork();
        printf("%d\n", pid_t);
        seccomp_release(ctx);
        return 0;
}
```

I compile like so:

```
hc01@HC01:~/torsocks$ gcc test_seccomp.c -lseccomp
```

Then run to get the following output:

```
hc01@HC01:~/torsocks$ ./a.out 
seccomp rule add return value: 0
seccomd_load return value: 0
15384
0
```

Implying that I was able to successfully fork and seccomp_add_rule and seccomp_load are running successfully. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't played around with it, but the man file makes me believe that you might want to try using SCMP_ACT_KILL_PROCESS instead

Comment: What do `seccomp_rule_add()` and `seccomp_load()` return?  You're not checking for any problems.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good idea! Unfortunately both do return 0

Comment: @visibleman strangely when I do that I get the error `error: ‘SCMP_ACT_KILL_PROCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork()` from glibc is likely actually using the system call `clone` instead of `fork`, see `man fork`.

You can verify this by having a look at `strace ./a.out`.

Therefore try:

```
rc = seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, SCMP_SYS(clone), 0);
```

instead.

You should in any case default-block and not default-allow syscalls, because otherwise you would need to consider all existing syscalls and whether they can have the undesired effect (e.g. for creating a child process there would be at least `vfork` in addition to `fork` and `clone`) and also because new kernel versions may add arbitrary syscalls which could again produce the undesired effect.

Comment: I assume things like this is why most examples of secomp  seem to use a default block and explicit allow setup.

Comment: @visibleman: The default block, explicit allow approach is the only sane one, because to retain binary backwards compatibility, the kernel is constantly sprouting new versions of older syscalls. Only blocking specific syscalls is .. well, like putting bars in your windows, but leaving all doors unlocked.

Comment: @user10605163 maybe you could consider adding some mention to that effect in in the answer?

Comment: @visibleman There's only a few very specific syscalls I need to block, but I see what you mean. I'll reconsider my approach. thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado You didn't write what exactly you want to prevent with the seccomp filter. I suppose if it really is only `do not call glibc's fork()`, then blocking `clone` only is fine, but if this is supposed to prevent malicious code from spawning processes, block-by-default would be much safer.